# Плавный скролл к якорю после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery

Имеется блок сортировки, сортировка выполняется на сервере. Нужно после перезагрузки страницы плавно проскролить к отсортированному контенту.

К url кнопок цепляю якоря #sort_anchor, в хедере перед загрузкой html захардкодил:

```
window.hashName = window.location.hash;
window.location.hash = '';
```

В шаблоне вызываю

```
$(window).load(function () {
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.hashName).offset().top-50},
500);
return false;});
```

Все работает, плавный скролл есть.
Но появилась ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Понимаю причину, как решить не знаю. Подскажите пл!

Comment: вы уверены что $(window.hashName) - есть такой элемент? Попробуйте удалить эту функцию анимации, если она вызывает ошибку и все работает то этот блок не нужен

Comment: Ваша ошибка означает, что элемента нету в DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При получении хеша  методом `window.location.hash` вам должно возвращать `#sort_anchor` что как понятно не может быть селектором.Вам надо отделить `#` от от полученной информации, например

```
         var  hash = window.location.hash.split('#');
    if(hash != undefined){
            window.location.hash = ''; 
            console.log(hash[1]);
        /* после проверки только можно сделать анимацию*/
              /*код анимации*/
        }
```

Comment: Код не работает в консоли undefined

Comment: а у вас в строке адреса имеется якорь #sort_anchor ? вы всегда при выполнении анимации должны проверять присутствие якоря

Comment: после перезагрузки n непродолжительное время #sort_anchor есть потом отрабатывает скрипт и оставляет #

Comment: а зачем вы удаляете якорь? в вашем примере вы удаляете способом   window.location.hash='' ;

Comment: якорь удаляю, потому что сервер сразу направит на якорь.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Arsen! победил!
Пример рабочего кода:

```
window.hashName = window.location.hash; //ложим в переменную
window.location.hash = ''; //очищаем хэш
if( window.hashName[1] != undefined){ //проверяем
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.hashName).offset().top-50}, 1500);
};
```